# New motor only rotates clockwise

Tags: arduino, wiring, hardware

I stared out with the 28byj-48 motor and got it to rotate one direction with one button and the other direction with the other button using Arduino pins 2 and 4, respectfully. When the new motor, pictured, is plugged in, I can only get it to rotate one way and it's made to go both ways. Pin 4 no longer responds when using this new motor.
How do I get the new motor to turn both ways?
Do I need to reorganize the 5 wires in the new motor and use a multimeter to determine the correct order or is the issue with some other part of this project?
I'm using the uln2003 driver board.
Thank you!

[image: new motor internal info]
[image: new motor outside info]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The new motor you are trying to use, what kind of motor is it? it might be a stepper motor, or the reason you cannot rotate it on the other direction is that its mechanically limited to rotate only on one direction.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the datasheet link for the motor.

Comment: That motor is a DC motor, but there is a component soldered to the leads. Make sure that component is not a diode. Five leads to a DC motor makes me think there is a PCB somewhere in between. Can we see that too?

Comment: Christianidis Vasileios, thank you for mentioning that, I updated my post, it is made to spend both ways. And, Transistor, I wish I had the data sheet to go with the new motor. It is a ProForm exercise bike pull off, all I have are the numbers included in the two pictures above.

Comment: as explained in your previous post, which you deleted, that is not a stepping motor ... it is just a DC motor ... it happens to have a potentiometer for position feedback ... you cannot just unplug a stepping motor and plug in this motor ... you have to drive the DC motor and read the potentiometer position

Comment: Thank you jsotola, I discovered I was not giving it enough power to rotate before. Now, I'm just not sure what is holding it back from rotating the other direction?

Comment: The 28byj-48 motor is a stepper that can be rotated in either direction if logic allows. It is a 4 phase 5V to each centre tap and 4 wires grounded by switches to ground in proper sequence gives 64 full steps per rev  or 8x 64 fractional steps.  But the picture is a brush gear DC motor with a pot. Not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the blue and yellow wires are going to the motor and the other wires are an encoder? 5K pot for position sensing? Looks like that was used as limited rotation servo. Component on the back of the motor looks like a filter capacitor to try to keep commutator noise out of the control circuit. Use a full Bridge motor driver to control the motor on the blue and yellow wires. Red wire to the Arduino Vcc and black to GND, white to an analog input. Make sure you don't drive that pot too far, 270 degrees or so is all it's likely to take before it breaks. You'll probably need to rewrite some code to make that work if you were using a stepper previously and just counting the steps in open loop mode to track the position. With this new setup, you'll need to run closed loop to prevent driving the servo mechanism too far.

Comment: ScienceGeyser, thank you so much, you rock! I would upvote your answer but apparently, I am too new.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new enough that I don't know if new OPs have the privilege to mark answers to their posts in any way. Maybe someone with a little more experience on this platform can chime in and educate us both. Or maybe we could RTFM? I'm hoping for someone to chime in since I'm not much a a manual reader myself. LOL! My 12 year old daughter always tells me I should use more acronyms.

Comment: Well tell your daughter I understand your whole message except for.. RTFM... Lol

Comment: Read The __ Manual... Use you favorite F word to replace the blank... Something like Fantastic, or Fabulous, etc...

Comment: Looks like the OP can mark one answer as "accepted" if that answer works for them. According to the manual.